# PDO - fetchAll syntax does not work

Tags: php, pdo

> General error: 2014 Cannot execute queries while other unbuffered
>   queries are active.    Consider using PDOStatement::fetchAll().
>   Alternatively, if your code is only ever going to run against mysql,
>   you may enable query buffering by setting the
>   PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_USE_BUFFERED_QUERY attribute.

My code:- create an select tag and populate it with records from database

```
<?php
    echo "<select name='test'>";
    $call = $dbh->prepare('call listmfg_codes()');
    $call->execute();
    $result = $call->fetchALL(PDO::FETCH_COLUMN, 0);
    foreach($result as $row)
    {
?>      
    <option value="<?php echo $row['mfg_code'];?>"><?php echo $row['mfg_code'];?>      </option>";
<?php       
}
echo "</select>"; 
?>
```

It does not seem to work. Please advise. Thanks

---

Then I tried to modify scripts again, so as to accommodate closeCurosr() and fetchAll(). Still it does not work

```
<?php
....
$stmt_call -> closeCursor();

echo "<select name='test'>";
$stmt_call = $dbh->prepare('call listmfg_codes()');
$stmt_call->execute();
foreach ($stmt_call -> fetchAll() as $row)
{
?>
<option value="<?php echo $row['mfg_code'];?>"> <?php echo $row['mfg_code'];?> </option>";
<?php       
}
echo "</select>";
?>
```

The same error persists even  thoght fetchAll() and closeCursor() are included.

I am still looking  for answers outside stachOverFlow. Please advise Thanks
Clement

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2421516/how-to-avoid-this-pdo-exception-cannot-execute-queries-while-other-unbuffered-q

Comment: What exactly is `call listmfg_codes()`??

Comment: it is mysql procedure, that is called by this script to perform by -"select distinct(mfg_code) from test;"

Answer (score 0):

The following code works for me.

```
<?php
    echo "<select name='test'>";
   $call = $dbh->prepare("SELECT DISTINCT(mfg_code) FROM test");
    $call->execute();
    $result = $call->fetchALL(PDO::FETCH_COLUMN, 0);
    foreach($result as $row)
    {
?>      
    <option value="<?php echo $row['mfg_code'];?>"><?php echo $row['mfg_code'];?>      </option>";
<?php       
}
echo "</select>"; 
}

?>
```

Comment: It does not really work. Still the same error. I suspected that it maybe be because of the repeated PDO executions of mysql scripts in one script though it cannot be ascertained. The only way is to break  the long script into two script files each having it's own PDO execution. And it worked.

Comment: There was no indication of repeated PDO executions in your question. It would be advisable if you indicate all relevant factors in any new question you ask